# Where is BitmapData?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, image-processing

Today I starded to port my C# desktop application to Windows Phone 7.5.

In my app, I do image processing. I need to use `BitmapData`, `LockBits`, `UnlockBits` and `Scan0.ToPointer()`, but it seems they aren't available for Windows Phone. What's the equivalent?

Comment: You do not have access to those library's in Silverlight. Look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048/image-cropping-c-sharp-without-net-library) to see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

The phone supports the compact framework - and 'compact' means that not everything in the full framework is available.

For image processing on the phone, I recommend you take a look at the writablebitmapex and imagetools libraries on nuget and on codeplex.

- http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/
- http://imagetools.codeplex.com/